# Don't include an operation for gradient computation in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, autograd

I have a custom layer. Let the layer be called 'Gaussian'

```
class Gaussian(nn.Module):
  def __init__():  
    super(Gaussian, self).__init__()
 
 #@torch.no_grad     
  def forward(self, x):
    _r = np.random.randint(0, x.shape[0], x.shape[0]) 
    _sample = x[_r] 
    _d = (_sample - x)
    _number = int(self.k * x.shape[0])
    x[1: _number] = x[1: _number] + (self.n * _d[1: _number]).detach()

    return x
```

The above class will be used as below:

```
cnn_model = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 5), Gaussian(), nn.ReLU(), nn.Conv2d(32, 32, 5))
```

If `x` is the input, I want the gradient of `x` to exclude operations that are present in the Gaussian module, but include the calculations in other layers of the neural network(nn.Conv2d etc).

In the end, my aim is to use the Gaussian module to perform calculations but that calculations should not be included in gradient computation.

I tried to do the following:

1. Used the @torch.no_grad above the forward method of the Gaussian
2. Using detach after every operation in the Gaussian module:

   `x[1: _number] = x[1: _number] + (self.n * _d[1: _number]).detach()` and similarly for other operations
3. Use y = x.detach() in the forward method. Perform the operations on y and then x.data = y

Are the above methods correct?

Comment: You can't. If other operations modify x. You'd break calculations.

Comment: So then I think, I can't use nn.Sequential in this case but should rather use other methods to define my network, right?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If other ops dont modify x, you can use ex. y=x.detach().item() and do ops on y. Otherwise it is against the logic of autograd other methods wont help you either.

Comment: What i want to achieve is, perform operations (which are part of the module 'Gaussian') on x which should not effect the gradients stored for x [The gradients stored are obtained from other operations not present in Gaussian module].           
So if I perform the operations on y (where y is initialized as y = x.detach() inside the gaussian module) and I pass on it's value back, such as x.data = y This wouldn't add any gradients on x because of operations on y, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient calculation has sense when there are parameters to optimise.

If your module do not have any parameters, then no gradient will be stored, because there are no parameters to associate it.

Comment: My neural net has parameters, so I need gradients to be stored. But yes in the module `Gaussian`, I don't define any nn.parameters but does that ensure gradients are not computed in the module?

Comment: Gradients are calculated and stored per module, considering the module s a group of parameters that will have a gradient. Since there are no defined parameters (e.g. with the `nn.parameters`), then no gradient will be calculated for your module.

Comment: Thank you very much. If possible can you please provide any reference from pytorch docs, so that I can know more.

Comment: Check the gradient mechanics in PyTorch. There is a whole section there about that. Also, check the theory of how to train a DNN model. The thing about the gradient is nothing peculiar to PyTorch, it is simply what it should be done, according to the theory and the backpropagation algorithm.